# cannot verify snap "gimp", no matching signatures found

Tags: snap, gimp, snap-store

I'm getting this error when I try and install the gimp snap how can this be fixed?

**Fetch and check assertions for snap "gimp" (412) (cannot verify snap "gimp", no matching signatures found)**

```
 rt@sys76:~$ sudo snap install gimp
    error: cannot perform the following tasks:
    - Fetch and check assertions for snap "gimp" (412) (cannot verify snap "gimp", no matching signatures found)
    rt@sys76:~$ 
    
    rt@sys76:~$ uname -a
    Linux sys76 5.15.0-91-generic #101~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 16 14:22:28 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

rt@sys76:~$ snap info gimp
name:      gimp
summary:   GNU Image Manipulation Program
publisher: Snapcrafters✪
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/gimp
contact:   https://github.com/snapcrafters/gimp/issues
license:   GPL-3.0+
description: |
  Whether you are a graphic designer, photographer, illustrator, or scientist, GIMP provides you
  with sophisticated tools to get your job done. You can further enhance your productivity with GIMP
  thanks to many customization options and 3rd party plugins.
  
  This snap is maintained by the Snapcrafters community, and is not necessarily endorsed or
  officially maintained by the upstream developers.
  
  Upstream Project: https://www.gimp.org/
  snapcraft.yaml Build Definition:
  https://github.com/snapcrafters/gimp/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml
snap-id: KDHYbyuzZukmLhiogKiUksByRhXD2gYV
channels:
  latest/stable:     2.10.36 2023-12-06 (412) 539MB -
  latest/candidate:  ↑                              
  latest/beta:       ↑                              
  latest/edge:       2.10.36 2023-12-06 (412) 539MB -
  preview/stable:    –                              
  preview/candidate: –                              
  preview/beta:      –                              
  preview/edge:      2.99.10 2022-08-17 (397) 650MB -

rt@sys76:~$ snap version
snap    2.61.1
snapd   2.61.1
series  16
ubuntu  20.04
kernel  5.15.0-91-generic
rt@sys76:~$
```